# Getting a "Missing Context For Method Declaration" implementing a map search bar in xcode

Tags: xcode

im getting an error that says "Missing Context For Method Declaration" when i implement this code into my viewcontroller.m:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:theSearchBar.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks,      NSError *error) {
        //Error checking

        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center.latitude = placemark.region.center.latitude;
        region.center.longitude = placemark.region.center.longitude;
        MKCoordinateSpan span;
        double radius = placemark.region.radius / 1000; // convert to km

        NSLog(@"[searchBarSearchButtonClicked] Radius is %f", radius);
        span.latitudeDelta = radius / 112.0;

        region.span = span;

        [theMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: what *line* of this method is that error appearing on?

Comment: its happening on "- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {"

Comment: Is the method defined *inside*  the `@implementation ... @end` block?

Comment: no its not... but when i add it inside the implementation it still pops up with the same error.